# Error: Electron packaging with electron-packager

Tags: node.js, npm, electron, electron-packager

I'm trying to package my ember-electron app using electron-packager.

This is for windows electron app running Ember-electron, ember-cli: 3.11.0, node: 10.16.0. In the past, it was running fine, but after deleting "electron-out", "dist" and "release-builds" folder I am getting an error.

```
{
    "name": "messenger",
    "productName": "Messenger",
    "version": "0.0.77",
    "main": "./ember-electron/main.js",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "build": "ember build",
        "package-win": "electron-packager . --project-path=electron-out/project --overwrite --platform=win32 --arch=x64 --icon=assets/messenger.ico --no-prune ---app-version=\"1.0.0.77\" --executable-name=\"Messenger\" --out=release-builds",

        "lint:hbs": "ember-template-lint .",
        "lint:js": "eslint .",
        "start": "ember serve",
        "test": "ember test"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^5.0.8",
    "electron-builder": "^20.40.2",
    "electron-forge": "^5.2.4",
    "electron-packager": "^14.0.2",
    "electron-prebuilt-compile": "3.0.2",
    "electron-winstaller": "^2.7.0",
    ....
}
```

Here is the error log I get:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli 'C:\\Users\\userName\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'package-win' ]
2 info using npm@6.10.1
3 info using node@v10.16.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prepackage-win', 'package-win', 'postpackage-win']
5 info lifecycle messenger@0.0.77~prepackage-win: messenger@0.0.77
6 info lifecycle messenger@0.0.77~package-win: messenger@0.0.77
7 verbose lifecycle messenger@0.0.77~package-win: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle messenger@0.0.77~package-win: PATH:C:\Users\userName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\messenger\New\client\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Emulator Manager\1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\;C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.6\;C:\PHP\;C:\Apache24\bin;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\cygwin64\bin;C:\Python27\Scripts\;C:\Python27\;C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Bandizip\;C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3;C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn;C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin;C:\PHP\;C:\Apache24\bin;C:\Users\userName\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\cygwin64\bin;
9 verbose lifecycle messenger@0.0.77~package-win: CWD: C:\messenger\New\client
10 silly lifecycle messenger@0.0.77~package-win: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'electron-packager . ' ]
11 silly lifecycle messenger@0.0.77~package-win: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle messenger@0.0.77~package-win: Failed to exec package-win script
13 verbose stack Error: messenger@0.0.77 package-win: `electron-packager . --project-path=electron-out/project --overwrite --platform=win32 --arch=x64 --icon=assets/messenger.ico --no-prune ---app-version=\"1.0.0.77\" --executable-name=\"Messenger\" --out=release-builds",`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous (C:\Users\userName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\userName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
14 verbose pkgid messenger@0.0.77
15 verbose cwd C:\messenger\New\client
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17763
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\userName\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "package-win"
18 verbose node v10.16.0
19 verbose npm  v6.10.1
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error messenger@0.0.77 package-win: `electron-packager . --project-path=electron-out/project --overwrite --platform=win32 --arch=x64 --icon=assets/messenger.ico --no-prune ---app-version=\"1.0.0.77\" --executable-name=\"Messenger\" --out=release-builds",`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the messenger@0.0.77 package-win script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Make sure to make your code more readable by putting it in a code block - it stops the text from wrapping, along with giving more scrolling area for longer samples. You can do this by putting four space characters in front of each line of code.

Comment: @Joseph thank you! This is my first post in stack overflow :) I'll keep it in mind

Comment: Maybe try electron-builder instead?

Comment: @MikeM Can you tell me how? Is it by customizing in electron-forge-config? I want to change the Properties->Detailed information of my program, but I don't know how

Comment: I will write this as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use **electron-builder** instead. I have written a [Medium article](https://medium.com/@michael.m/creating-an-electron-and-react-template-5173d086549a) documenting this in detail, and you can find my [complete project](https://github.com/mmick66/electrate) on GitHub.

But apart from that, here is a quick overview. First add [electron-builder](https://www.electron.build/):

```
npm install electron-builder --save-dev
```

For `electron-builder` to work, you need to indicate which files must be included in the build. You do that through a build key in your `package.json`. Let's say that you compile your files in a folder called `app/`. Then you only need to add their dependencies found in the node_modules folder (remember, a standalone app must contain **everything**). So add a "build" key in your `package.json`:

```
"build": {
  "appId": "com.electron.build.example",
  "files": [
    "app/**/*",
    "node_modules/**/*",
    "package.json"
  ],
  "publish": null
}
```

Add the script that calls for a (release) build:

```
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "install-app-deps",
  "start": "gulp start",
  "release": "gulp release"
},
```

I used [gulp](https://gulpjs.com/), but you can use anything you want (or even call electron-builder straight from npm). It's up to you. In my case, I only needed to include the task in my gulp file. Notice that I used `exec` rather than `spawn` so as to be cross-compilable for Windows machines.

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
gulp.task('release', ['build'], () => {
    return exec(        
        __dirname+'/node_modules/.bin/electron-builder .'
    ).on('close', () => process.exit());
});
```

Comment: `electron-builder` is wayyy more confusing than `electron-packager`, and your article on medium doesnt help at all :/

Comment: finally got it working. damn tutorials have the wrong values for the JSON properties. is there any way to allow the user to choose which folder in which the executable is installed/unpacked?

Comment: Please, can you tell me if the code above (which I updated just now) works for you?

Comment: im not using gulp. never have used it so not sure how to

Comment: Ok, I am just curious what you meant when you said "damn tutorials have the wrong values for the JSON properties"

Comment: i came across some video tutorial on YT and some article tutorials that were using `build` as the key for the `dist` in the property of `scripts` when in fact the value for `dist` should have been `electron-builder`. this fact is kind of buried in the documentation, so i overlooked it while skimming the documentation

Comment: I see... ok, I have come across this issue myself. I think that `build` is like `start`, it's a special key that does certain things for electron automatically, so in theory it should work, but not for us apparently. I was only asking whether you spotted mistakes on my tutorial so I could make the appropriate changes. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Hey @oldboy, how did you fix this?

Comment: @IkerOcioZuazo i cannot remember. sorry